# Add .js file in root folder from xml, Magento version 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, xml

Is it possible to add in xml configuration .js file from root folder. In root folder we have the folder js_components. How can I add a file in xml? I can not move this "js_components" folder 
in default "js" folder.

```
            <action method="addJs"><script>js_components/test.js</script></action>
```

Comment: please specify Magento version

Comment: We can not do that by XML  because Magento searching `js`,`skin_js`,`js_css` values in params

Answer (score 0):

Kunj, Thank you for your answer. I found how to solve it:

```
            <action method="addJs"><script>../js_components/test.js</script></action>
```